# Dynamically building up types in python

Tags: python, types, metaprogramming

Suppose I am building a composite set of types:

```
def subordinate_type(params):
   #Dink with stuff
   a = type(myname, (), dict_of_fields)
   return a()

def toplevel(params)
    lots_of_types = dict(keys, values)
    myawesomedynamictype = type(toplevelname, (), lots_of_types)

    #Now I want to edit some of the values in myawesomedynamictype's 
    #lots_of_types. 

    return myawesomedynamictype()
```

In this particular case, I want a reference to the "typeclass" `myawesomedynamictype` inserted into lots_of_types.

I've tried to iterate through `lots_of_types` and set it, supposing that the references were pointed at the same thing, but I found that the `myawesomedynamictype` got corrupted and lost its fields.

The problem I'm trying to solve is that I get values related to the  type `subordinate_type`, and I need to generate a `toplevel` instantiation based on `subordinate_type`.

Comment: Could you post some toy code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: why your base class is not `object`?

Comment: @SilentGhost: it doesn't seem needful.

Comment: But **for what specific purpose** did you need a reference to the "typeclass" *myawesomedynamictype* inserted into *lots_of_types*? This can only be to access a constructor, method (or member) later, or else for type checking, or implementing inheritance in some weird way. None of which sound Pythonic - what do you later use that reference for?

Comment: @smci: I have no clue anymore as to the specifics of the problem. This was nearly a year ago. I was doing some metaprogramming.

Comment: Ok, but whatever it was, that's not the Pythonic way to do it.

Comment: @smci: So what. The goal's to get the solution solved, not to conform to some ideal.

Comment: @Paul Nathan: this code is a total hack, and That Way Lies Trouble.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ancient question, and because it's not clear what the code is trying to do (being a code gist rather than working code), it's a little hard to answer.

But it sounds like you want a reference to the dynamically created class "myawesomedynamictype" on the class itself.  A copy of (I believe a copy of) the dictionary lots_of_types became the `__dict__` of this new class when you called type() to construct it.

So, just set a new attribute on the class to have a value of the class you just constructed; Is that what you were after?

```
def toplevel(params)
    lots_of_types = dict(keys, values)
    myawesomedynamictype = type(toplevelname, (), lots_of_types)
    myawesomedynamictype.myawesomedynamictype = myawesomedynamictype
    return myawesomedynamictype()
```